# How can I easily log some specific command line commands into a file?

Tags: bash

I often perform configuration changes using single line commands on Mac OS, Linux or even Windows and I want to easily log them in a file, so I can replay if I have to reconfigure the machine again.

Please not that I want to do these only for some commands, so the shell history is of not use.

Ideally I would like to be able to use some kind of shell extension that logs some of the commands.

As you know if you start your bash command with a space, this command is not logged into the history.

What if I can have another prefix that would do the opposite? Is there something there that can be used for this? A solution for bash would be more than enough and if there is an already existing solution it would much better than me writing a new one.

Comment: If you execute commands from time to time to configure machines put them into shellscripts, or even better, use a configuration mangement tool.

Comment: Do these "single line commands" involve pipes and compound commands?

Comment: Yes, some of them would involve compound commands.

Comment: @hek2mgl i need to log these in order to be able to put them later into configuration management, but at the time you run them you certainly do not have time to do them. The whole point is easily log some of the commands.

Comment: What stops you from opening a text editor and save a command line for later use? If you don't have time to do proper work then take a breath. I don't see the issue here. Furthermore, bash history interaction commands offer a powerful way to browse the history and execute earlier commands again.

Answer (score 1):

You could do your logging in `PROMPT_COMMAND`, extracting the specific commands from shell history and writing them to a file.

Something like:

```
log () { 
    last_command="$(history -p \!\!)"
    if [[ $last_command == "  "* ]]    # save commands starting with *two* spaces
    then
         printf "%s\n" "$last_command" >> ~/special.log
    fi
}
PROMPT_COMMAND="log; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

This has problems:

1. `PROMPT_COMMAND` is run each time the prompt is printed. Just pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> multiple times could cause a command to be logged multiple times.
2. Marking with two spaces would, of course, need you to remove `ignorespace` or `ignoreboth` from `HISTCONTROL` so that commands starting spaces are logged at all.
3. AFAICT, history is updated when the next command is read, so the command is logged after the next command returns to the prompt, since that's when the correct history is available in `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

---

All this would be easier in zsh, with a `preexec` hook:

```
preexec () {     
    if [[ $1 == "  "* ]]
    then
        printf "%s\n" "$1" >> ~/special.log
    fi
}
```

The `preexec` function automatically gets the command as the first argument if history is enabled, saving us a deal of trouble. It is run when the command has been read, but before it begins execution, so the timing is perfect. From [the documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-hook-functions):

> `preexec`
>
> Executed just after a command has been read and is about to be
>   executed. If the history mechanism is active (regardless of whether
>   the line was discarded from the history buffer), the string that the
>   user typed is passed as the first argument, otherwise it is an empty
>   string. The actual command that will be executed (including expanded
>   aliases) is passed in two different forms: the second argument is a
>   single-line, size-limited version of the command (with things like
>   function bodies elided); the third argument contains the full text
>   that is being executed.

```
$   ls
$   echo foo | echo bar
bar
$ cat ~/special.log    
  ls
  echo foo | echo bar
```

Answer (score 0):

A function in .bashrc can be used like a prefix:

```
log_this_command () {
    echo "$@" >> ~/a_log_file # log the command to file
    "$@"                      # and run the command itself
}
```

Caveat: this only logs expanded arguments, rather than the raw input.

Answer (score -1):

- Source function with the same name *`function screencapture {echo "used parms: $@"; command screencapture $@}`*
- appending to log file `function screencapture {echo "$(date) screencapture " $@ >> ~/log.txt; command screencapture $@}`

as one runs `screencapture` command, log entry is created and command executes as uninterfered

---

you could automate in creating these functions, if the list of them is like .... all of them